# IE7 float bug workaround?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I have the following HTML:

```
<div><span>left</span><span style="float:right;">right</span></div>
```

For some reason, the float:right, floats to the right, but goes down 1 line too.  Why is this happening and is there a work around?

Here is a jsfiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/CxaW6/

But it will only show the bug if you are looking at the link via IE7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the other span float left will fix this.

```
<div><span style="float:left;">left</span><span style="float:right;">right</span></div>
```

Usually `span` is treated as an inline element. IE7 seems to handle them differently and so extending the width (within the layout process) of the first span to 100%. In this case there is not enough space for the other span in this line, so it will be wrapped to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

You can either float the span left explicitly with `float: left` (my preferred solution) or put the right-floated span first in the markup. The issue is to do with IE7 giving a virtual full width to the first span, causing the second span to render on the 'next' line.

Answer (score 0):

Float the first span to the left, or float the first span to the right and remove the float property from the second.

Comment: Or alternately, put the right span BEFORE the left span. That works as well.